# Keeping track of Hash Factory Objects

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hash

I have a hashfactory that returns a dynamically allocated object.

```
Item * Class::foo()
{
   int subscript = hash(someKey);
   return factory[subscript]->create();
}

//function create() is an overridden function in an inherited class that returns Item *

Item *SomeClass::create()
{
   return new SomeClass();
}
```

In order for me not to have memory leaks, do I have to ensure that every pointer that touches this ends up being assigned to NULL and the final pointer that is keeping track of it is deleted and then set to NULL?

Comment: [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)?

Comment: No, no Boost allowed. This is for a C++ class. Why not use boost and other goodies? Because the professor doesn't want you to. Non-negotiable.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<>` is standard now if you're not using an ancient compiler -- no Boost necessary, just `#include <memory>`. In any case, if you have that sort of limitation, it's best to say so up front in your question, _especially_ if it's `homework`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

1. If this is your own class in your own project **you are** indeed **responsible for deleting** the memory that is allocated by you calling create() (or foo()).
2. If this is a library class you have created, and you have **documented** it well enough, the **caller** of your library code will be **responsible for deleting the memory** created by a call to foo().

In either way, you have to set things straight and either document or implement proper memory management.

Comment: Encouraging use of raw pointers over smart pointers is just silly.

Comment: Raw pointers have their use. I suggest reading "C++ Coding Standards" by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu. Moreover, (to cite Mike "Mr. Mike" McShaffry) "All smart pointers wear clothing." (read "Game Coding Complete, 3rd Ed." by "Mr. Mike" for a throughout explanation). After all, C++ is not Java (or C# or whatever fancy wannabe replacement you want to put in to avoid your fear of memory access).

Comment: Raw pointers have exactly two uses: being wrapped by smart pointers, and C interop. Those books predate TR1 and C++11; now that smart pointers are part of the _standard_, I'd be frankly amazed if new editions discouraged their use in any fashion (especially considering that `std::unique_ptr<>` has absolutely zero overhead, which is the usual excuse for avoiding smart pointers).

Comment: I personally think encouraging programmers to more and more not think about the memory they use (and accordingly alignment) will produce more and more bad programmers. Having a wrapper is also no excuse for not understanding whats going on under the hood.

Comment: Nobody said people shouldn't understand memory management and pointers in general, but the simple fact is that avoiding something that is easy to get wrong in favor of something that is harder to get wrong _and no less efficient_ is simple common sense.

Comment: But people **wont** (i don't know how to make italics in comments, sorry ;) understand how things work if they are hit in their face every time they use a "*" in their code. I've seen this enough and I have seen smart pointer implementations fail badly (why would I need an explicit construcor there?) - learners won't get anywhere if even experts fail. The OP wouldn't have asked the question if he/she weren't a learner. I answered it, thats it - his acceptance raises hope in me he understood the matter, thats all it is about. Btw, factories are perfect candidates (tb continued)

Comment: for C interfaces (where raw pointers are necessary). Just to name one that has been laid down dead and is about to raise: COM.